# Calculate bitlength of very large number strings

Tags: javascript

`bigIntString` is a string containing a large number. Now I need to find out the bitlength. So far I've been doing it this way:

```
Math.ceil(Math.log(bigIntString) / Math.log(2))
```

This has been working well up to ~1024 bit numbers. However, for bigger numbers, I'm only getting "Infinity" since it converts the string to a number.

Is there any trick to find out the bit length of such big number-strings without having to use a bigint library?

Comment: Do you need an exact result?  Assuming your strings contain decimal representations, then you can estimate the number of bits as `numDecimalDigits * log2(10)`.

Comment: What's your _maximum_ value that you need to work with - any limitation? Also, do you need to do this for the occasional number now and then, or for a large quantity and with high performance?

Comment: Hmmm, yes an exact result would be great. What would also work if it would round up to the next highest 2^n, so 1024, 2048, 4096 (I think that's the maximum I need to handle) since these are keys of some public key encryption systems. But since I'm not sure this is even possible, thanks for your suggestion of the estimtae!

Comment: `const digits = 0; while(+bigIntString > 2 ** digits) digits++;`

Comment: hmm with with `const` it cannot increment digits so I changed it to `let`. Also, for some reason it only works up to 1024 bits.